# D3: Collision/overlap detection of circles in a generated view

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3 to animate some circles that are representing some tools, that you are able to drag and drop. I'd like to be able to create a function that detects when two circles/g elements collide with eachother.

I already have a lot of code but this is the concerned code that i would like to modify. I'm really just trying to determine if there is a way to detect when the circle/g element collides or overlaps any of the other

```
        function circCollide(g) {
            node = g;
            nodeBox = g.getBBox();
            nodeLeft = nodeBox.x;
            nodeRight = nodeBox.x + nodeBox.width;
            nodeTop = nodeBox.y;
            nodeBottom = nodeBox.y + nodeBox.height;

            d3.selectAll(g)
                .attr("fill", function() {
                    if (this !== node) {
                        otherBox = this.getBBox();

                        otherLeft = otherBox.x;
                        otherRight = otherBox.x + otherBox.width;
                        otherTop = otherBox.y;
                        otherBottom = otherBox.y + otherBox.height;

                        collideHoriz = nodeLeft < otherRight && nodeRight > otherLeft;
                        collideVert = nodeTop < otherBottom && nodeBottom > otherTop;

                        if ( collideHoriz && collideVert) {
                            return "tomato";
                        } else {
                            return "none"
                        }

                    } else {
                        return "none";
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

Right now i get the the following error ("Uncaught TypeError: g.getBBox is not a function")
How do i fix it and make my collision detection work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g` contains the d3 selection, whereas `getBBox` is a function which is tied to the [DOM node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox).

The DOM node can be accessed from the d3 selection using `selection.node`function.

Try the following:

```
nodeBox = g.node().getBBox();
```

This said, you might want to use `getBoundingClientRect` instead of `getBBox`, in order to get accurate values (e.g. taking transformations into account); c.f. article linked above for details.

Comment: Thanks it works! Now i dont get the error anymore.

But when i execute the generateAxixsView() and the circles pop up, the console prints ("No collision detected")

And then when i drag and drop a circle on top of eachother it does not print ("Collision detected")

Comment: You might want to  call `circCollide` inside the `dragended` function...

Comment: Yea i did that:) But it always returns "No collision detected" when i drop the circle, not  matter what

Comment: You could ask a separate question since this is a different problem. It would help to have a reproducible example in a stack snippet.